# Using a do while loop with a user inputted String

Tags: java

Am currently working on a question for my Java class, I'm doing do-while loops and I'm having trouble when my while condition has to do with a user inputted String. The code compiles but no matter what I enter it fails the while condition and does the loop again. This even occurred when I hardcoded the value of unit.

I tried looking up the solution online but every example I can find uses a user inputted int value instead of a String

```
public class unit {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      String prompt = "Please enter your preferred unit of mass (kg, lb, g or oz): ";
      System.out.println(preferredUnit(prompt));
   }
   
   public static String preferredUnit(String prompt) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String unit = "";
            
      do{
         if (!unit.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Sorry but " + unit + " is not a valid unit type");
         }
         System.out.println(prompt);
         unit = sc.nextLine();
      
      }  while(!unit.equals("kg") || !unit.equals("lb") || !unit.equals("g") || !unit.equals("oz") );
      
      return "Unit of mass: " + unit; 
   }
}
```

Comment: The Problem in your while loop condition.

Comment: It always return true. Because when you enter anything it will check !unit.equals("kg") return true. so It's OR operator. One of them is true mean While run again

Comment: Use && Operator Instead of ||.

Answer (score 1):

```
!=A || !=B
```

is not what you're looking for. If I enter A, it's not B, so it fails. If I enter B, it's not A, so it fails. Instead you're looking for `!=A && !=B`

E.g.

```
while(!unit.equals("kg") || !unit.equals("lb") || !unit.equals("g") || !unit.equals("oz"))
```

Should be

```
while(!unit.equals("kg") && !unit.equals("lb") && !unit.equals("g") && !unit.equals("oz"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible Fixed of your problem.

One Way:

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {
      String prompt = "Please enter your preferred unit of mass (kg, lb, g or oz): ";
      System.out.println(preferredUnit(prompt));
   }
   
   public static String preferredUnit(String prompt) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String unit = "";
            
      do{
         if (!unit.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Sorry but " + unit + " is not a valid unit type");
         }
         System.out.println(prompt);
         unit = sc.nextLine();
      
      }  while(!unit.equals("kg") && !unit.equals("lb") && !unit.equals("g") && !unit.equals("oz") );
      
      return "Unit of mass: " + unit; 
   }
```

Second way:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
      String prompt = "Please enter your preferred unit of mass (kg, lb, g or oz): ";
      System.out.println(preferredUnit(prompt));
   }
   
   public static String preferredUnit(String prompt) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String unit = "";
            
      do{
         if (!unit.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Sorry but " + unit + " is not a valid unit type");
         }
         System.out.println(prompt);
         unit = sc.nextLine();
      
      }  while(!(unit.equals("kg") || unit.equals("lb") || unit.equals("g") || unit.equals("oz")) );
      
      return "Unit of mass: " + unit; 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `do-while` loop says: `do something while a condition is true`.
Your condition is:

```java
   !unit.equals("kg") || !unit.equals("lb") || !unit.equals("g") || !unit.equals("oz")
```

and it must be `false` to exit from the `do-while` loop.
If you enter `kg`, the first condition (`!unit.equals("kg")`) is `false` and it is what you want, but unfortunately, because the next condition (`!unit.equals("lb")`) is `true` and it is in *OR* (`||`), you remain in the `do-while` loop whatever is your input.
You need to change the condition using *AND* (`&&`):

```java
   !unit.equals("kg") && !unit.equals("lb") && !unit.equals("g") && !unit.equals("oz")
```